# Making logs available to Stackdriver from a Custom Kubernetes docker container running Apache and PHP-FPM

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes, stackdriver, fpm

We are running a small test cluster of Custom Kubernetes pods on Google cloud, that internally are running Apache and PHP-FPM.

The Cluster has the following key config:

- Master version: 1.10.6-gke.2
- Kubernetes alpha features: Disabled
- Total size: 3
- StackDriver Logging: Enabled
- StackDriver Monitoring:
  Enabled

Once the cluster comes up a *kubectl get pods --all-namespaces* is showing the fluentd and heapster services running along side our services as I would expect.

```
kube-system   event-exporter-v0.2.1-5f5b89fcc8-r89d5                           2/2       Running   0          13d
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-scaler-7c5db745fc-gbrqx                              1/1       Running   0          21d
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-76mr4                                         2/2       Running   0          13d
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-kl4xp                                         2/2       Running   0          13d
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-vxsq5                                         2/2       Running   0          13d
kube-system   heapster-v1.5.3-95c7549b8-fdlmm                                  3/3       Running   0          13d
kube-system   kube-dns-788979dc8f-c9v2d                                        4/4       Running   0          99d
kube-system   kube-dns-788979dc8f-rqp7d                                        4/4       Running   0          99d
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler-79b4b844b9-zjtwk                             1/1       Running   0          99d
```

We can get the logging from our application code (that runs inside our pods) to show up in Stackdriver Logging, but we want to aggregate the logging for Apache (/var/log/httpd/access_log and error_log) and PHP-FPM in Stackdriver as well.

This page from Google's Docs implies that this should be enabled by default.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/logging

*Note: Stackdriver Logging is enabled by default when you create a new cluster using the gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Platform Console.*

However that is obviously not the case for us. We have tried a few different approaches to get this to work (listed below), but without success.

Including:

- redirecting the log output from Apache to stdout and/or stderr, as described in this post.
  https://serverfault.com/questions/711168/writing-apache2-logs-to-stdout-stderr
- Installing the stackdriver agent inside each pod as described in https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/apache#configuring

It didn't appear that this step should be required as the documentation implies that you only need to do this on a VM instance, but we tried it anyway on our k8s pods. As part of this step we made sure that Apache has mod_status enabled (/server-status) and PHP-FPM has /fpm-status enabled, and then installed the module Apache plugin following the docs.

- Piping the Apache logging to STDOUT
  [How to Redirect Apache Logs to both STDOUT and Apache Log File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483974/how-to-redirect-apache-logs-to-both-stdout-and-apache-log-file)

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but we have obviously missed something. Any help would be most appreciated.

Cheers, Julian Cone

Comment: Have you tried using the Google Cloud Logging Driver for Docker?[This](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) tutorial shows you how to use the Google Cloud logging driver to upload logs from your Docker containers to Stackdriver Logging.

Comment: Thanks Digil, that looks useful. Not sure how we didn't find that page in the Google documentation. I will give that a crack and report back on how I get on.